# How to find all actual type declaration of Java generic parameter in intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public class SomeEvent<T extends Serializable> {
    T value;
}

class A {
    int x = 1;
    SomeEvent<String> a = new SomeEvent<>(); // 1
    SomeEvent y = new SomeEvent();
    SomeEvent<Long> b = new SomeEvent<>(); // 2
}
```

In this case, I want ide highlight

`SomeEvent<String> a = new SomeEvent<>();`

and

`SomeEvent<Long> b = new SomeEvent<>();`.

Because actually generic params for `T` are explicitly declared as `String` and `Long` there.

What I actually want to find out are `String` `Long` in this case.

### update:

press `Ctrl + B` (declarations or usages) on `SomeEvent` makes some sense, but it may cause to much result (because I just want the type  declaration with actual generic parameter like `SomeEvent<String> a = new SomeEvent<>();` but not all usages).

Comment: "but it may cause to much result." It's unclear what results you *don't* want?

Comment: updated my description:  I just want the type declaration with actual generic parameter like `SomeEvent<String> a = new SomeEvent<>();` but not all usages

Comment: Ah so you don't want to find e.g. `SomeEvent<Double>` or `SomeEvent<Integer>`. Is that right?

Comment: I want them, since `SomeEvent<String> a` it has actual generic parameter for `SomeEvent`

Comment: I just want the type declaration with actual generic parameter like `SomeEvent<String> a = new SomeEvent<>();` but not usages like `event instanceof SomeEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Structure Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-work-with-structural-search-and-replace.html) can help here. It can be accessed in Edit -> Find -> Search Structurally.

You can create a search template like this:

```
SomeEvent<$Type$>
```

If you want, you can add a count filter to `$Type$`, with a minimum of 0. This will also find places where you call the constructor without specifying type arguments, like `new SomeEvent<>()`, in addition to things like `SomeEvent<String> event;`.

If you don't want to find usages where `$Type$` is a type parameter, you can add a Reference=Classes filter too.

[image]